# Identical DHCP leases, excessive dhcp traffic

Tags: centos, iptables, dhcp, android, webmin

Fresh install of CentOS 7, removed dnsmasq, installed dhcp server, iptables, webmin, apache.

This is school and lot of switches and wifi (bridge mode) AP's connected to this router

One network - 10.0.0.0

DHCP pool - 10.5.0.1 - 10.5.244.244

There is static leases (around 100)

I get excessive messages like http://pastebin.com/gXGtr3Y8

```
Apr  1 08:03:30 int dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from a4:ee:57:e0:91:df via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:31 int dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.5.20.90 to a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:32 int dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:32 int dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.5.20.90 to a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:32 int dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.5.20.90 (10.0.0.1) from a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:32 int dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.5.20.90 to a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
Apr  1 08:03:34 int dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.5.20.90 (10.0.0.1) from a4:ee:57:e0:91:df (EPSONE091DF) via enp28s1
```

which leads to

```
    10.5.20.90  a4:ee:57:e0:91:df   EPSONE091DF 2016/04/01 05:03:32 2017/04/01 10:52:18
    10.5.20.90  a4:ee:57:e0:91:df   EPSONE091DF 2016/04/01 05:03:34 2017/04/01 10:52:20
    10.5.20.90  a4:ee:57:e0:91:df   EPSONE091DF 2016/04/01 05:03:36 2017/04/01 10:52:22
    10.5.20.90  a4:ee:57:e0:91:df   EPSONE091DF 2016/04/01 05:03:39 2017/04/01 10:52:25
    10.5.20.90  a4:ee:57:e0:91:df   EPSONE091DF 2016/04/01 05:03:40 2017/04/01 10:52:26
```

Also, most of the Android devices struggles to connect to wifi. http://pastebin.com/UMsg7jS7

Could you guide me in right direction?
Ask for more information if required :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there were some WiFi AP's with old static IP addresses, so after making them DHCP, problem went away.